# Calling PlayerMoveEvent instance method

Tags: java, api, methods, bukkit

I am simply trying to call a method, but I'm a bit lost on how to do so with the parameters I need to use from the Bukkit API.

**The method I'm calling:**

```
@EventHandler   
    private void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        Location location = loc.get(player.getName());
        if (player.getLocation().distance(location) >= 65) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Out of reach.");
        }
    }
```

**The method I'm calling it from:**

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandlabel, String[] args) {
    this.onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should be having an instance of `PlayerMoveEvent` to pass to the method.

Comment: @Ravinder How do you suggest I do that when converting `PlayerMoveEvent` to `event`?

Comment: You should be having a reference class variable on `PlayerMoveEvent`. Pass it to the method, if it got instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call events, they're automatically triggered when the event happens. For example,

```
@EventHandler   
public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent event){
}
```

Would be called when a player moves. You will **NEVER** need to call an event.

If what you're trying to do is teleport a player, you could use:

```
Player p; //make sure that 'p' is assigned to something
Location l = new Location(world, x-coord, y-coord, z-coord);

p.teleport(l);
```

So, what you should really be doing is, considering this is all in your main file:

```
@Override
public void onEnable(){
    //plugin enabled
    this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
}

@Override
public void onDisable(){
    //plugin disabled
}

@EventHandler   
public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent event){ //NEVER make events with the private modifier
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    Location location = loc.get(player.getName()); //I really don't know what your trying to do here
    //if your trying to create a new location, check out the code above
    if(player.getLocation().distance(location) >= 65) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Out of reach.");
    }
}
```

Your `onPlayerMove` method will be called whenever a player moves, no extra work necessary!

Also, make sure the `player.getLocation().distance(location)` actually works, as it isn't a method in Bukkit... I'm assuming you get the distance between the player's location, and `location`, by checking the players `X`, `Y`, and `Z` coords...

Just make sure that the class in which you're putting the event in `implements Listener`

Also, If you would like to put the event in a class other than your Main file, to register events in your `onEnable()`, use this:

```
this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new classNameHere(), this);
```

If it's in your main file, you could replace `new classNameHere()` with `this`

One last time though, and I can't stress how important this is, you ***NEVER*** have to call your event methods. As long as the events are registered (done in the code above), and the methods have `@EventHandler` above them. Events will ***ALWAYS*** be called automatically whenever the event happens

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.  What I am trying to do is have it record their location when they type a command, and then if they move farther than 65 blocks away from that previously set location, send them a message.  Any ideas on how I would set that initial location?

Comment: @swiftsly yes, you could use a `HashMap` storing the player's name & location `Map<String,Location>`, then, when they type the command, use `map.get(player.getName())`, which will return the location from the map, then, get the `X` and `Z` coords of the location, if `player.getLocation().getX() <= mapLocation.getX() - 65 || player.getLocation.getX() >= mapLocation.getX() + 65`, then do the same for the X coord